# Deleting/keeping schema.rb after switching to structure.sql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-schema

Is there any point in keeping `schema.rb` after switching to `structure.sql`?

Or is it imperative that it should be deleted in order to avoid conflicts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no point in keeping `schema.rb`.

The purpose of `schema.rb` is to be the authoritive, up-to-date reference for the database schema which developers can use to setup the test and development environments. Once you switch the setting over to a SQL schema `schema.rb` will no longer be updated when migrations are run. Its then about as useful as last years bus schedule and will only cause confusion.